# Почему может не работать js-анимация на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Внезапно стала нужна кнопка "наверх". Загуглил, нашёл код на jsfiddle, проверил - работает:

Скопировал к себе на сайт, но у меня на сайте не работает анимация. Вместо `.fadeIn()` и `fadeOut()` у меня просто резко появляется и исчезает элемент, а `.animate({scrollTop : 0},800)` не анимирует плавный скролл вверх, а просто сразу резко кидает в самый верх без анимации. Есть какие-то предположения? Возможно, я что-то упустил?

**UPD:** кнопка лежит в конце страницы перед  скриптами. Я сделал анимацию появления и исчезновения при помощи css, но `scrollTop` всё равно не проигрывает анимацию, а резко бросает вверх.

**UDP2:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.scrollToTop').addClass('visible');
    } else {
      $('.scrollToTop').removeClass('visible');
    }
  });

  //Click event to scroll to top
  $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
  width: 500px;
}

.scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 45px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #039be5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #039be5 0%, #0288d1 90%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.scroll-to-top.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.scroll-to-top>i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="#" class="scroll-to-top">
  <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
</a>
```

Comment: Добавьте html и css элемента и его окружения в условие. Параметры css, такие, как, например "transition" раньше ломали анимацию jquery.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был подключён модуль jQuery Easing, который и блокировал всю анимацию jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Слушай я в JQ  не силен, просто не пишу на нем...  вот пример на чистом JS

```js
var scrollingUp;
var timer;
var scroll_to_top = document.querySelector('.scroll-to-top')



document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 100) {
    scroll_to_top.classList.add('visible')

  } else {
    scroll_to_top.classList.remove('visible')

  }
})

scroll_to_top.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scrollingUp = window.pageYOffset;
  winScrollUp();
})

function winScrollUp() {

  if (scrollingUp > 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollingUp);
    scrollingUp = scrollingUp - 10;
    timer = setTimeout(winScrollUp, 1)

  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
}

.scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 45px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #039be5;
  background-image: url('http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/10/464/w512h5121380984855up.png');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.scroll-to-top.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-to-top"></div>
```

Comment: Не сработало...

Comment: ну тогда добавь и html и  css

Comment: Всё равно не работает

Comment: ты не понял, html и css добавь сюда, что бы  пример был наглядным, а не только JS

Comment: Добавил снипет в вопрос