# Скролл при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть навбар, надо что бы при нажатии на ссылку он плавно перекидывал на нужную секцию.

Как сделать это без помощи JQ? Не хочу подключать целую библиотеку ради этой функции.

Comment: Обычный якорь не подойдет?

Comment: ну а сам что сделал? что именно не получается...?  вот пример плавного перехода   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722375/Почему-может-не-работать-js-анимация-на-сайте/722477#722477

Comment: Нет, не подойдет, нужен плавный скролл

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример моего древнего кода плавного скролла наверх, переделать под ваши условия думаю будет не сложно.

```
var toTopButton = document.getElementById('scroll-to-top');
if (toTopButton) {
    Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) {
            return c/2*t*t + b
        }
        t--;
        return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    };

    var requestAnimFrame = (function(){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function( callback ){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };
    })();

    function scrollToTop() {
        function move(amount) {
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = amount;
            document.body.parentNode.scrollTop = amount;
            document.body.scrollTop = amount;
        }
        function position() {
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.parentNode.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        var start = position(),
            currentTime = 0,
            increment = 20;
        var animateScroll = function() {
            currentTime += increment;
            var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, -start, 300);
            move(val);
            if (currentTime < 300) {
                requestAnimFrame(animateScroll);
            } 
        };
        animateScroll();
    }
    toTopButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollToTop();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// собираем все якоря; устанавливаем время анимации и количество кадров
const anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')),
      animationTime = 300,
      framesCount = 20;

anchors.forEach(function(item) {
  // каждому якорю присваиваем обработчик события
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // убираем стандартное поведение
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // для каждого якоря берем соответствующий ему элемент и определяем его координату Y
    let coordY = document.querySelector(item.getAttribute('href')).getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    // запускаем интервал, в котором
    let scroller = setInterval(function() {
      // считаем на сколько скроллить за 1 такт
      let scrollBy = coordY / framesCount;
      
      // если к-во пикселей для скролла за 1 такт больше расстояния до элемента
      // и дно страницы не достигнуто
      if(scrollBy > window.pageYOffset - coordY && window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset < document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // то скроллим на к-во пикселей, которое соответствует одному такту
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollBy);
      } else {
        // иначе добираемся до элемента и выходим из интервала
        window.scrollTo(0, coordY);
        clearInterval(scroller);
      }
    // время интервала равняется частному от времени анимации и к-ва кадров
    }, animationTime / framesCount);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.navbar{
  height:60px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;

}
ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}
li{
  margin-right:2rem;
}
#about_us{
  background:red;
}
#contacts{
  background:blue;
}
#services{
  background:green;
}
#about_us, #contacts, #services{
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#navbar">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about_us">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="about_us">
  About us
</div>
<div id="contacts">
  Contacts
</div>
<div id="services">
  Services
</div>
```