# Плавная прокрутка к якорям JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли реализовать плавную прокрутку к якорям на `нативном JS`?

Раньше пользовался `JQuery`

```
 $("a.scrollto").click(function() {
    var elementClick = $(this).attr("href")
    var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
    jQuery("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
        scrollTop: destination
    }, 500);
    return false;
 });
```

Но хочется уйти от `JQuery`, заранее спасибо!

Comment: [Пример тут](https://codepen.io/AnotherLinuxUser/pen/eZxoQp). Я нашёл его при помощи поиска в **`GOOGLE`**, первая ссылка по запросу **`smooth scroll pure js`**

Comment: разрешите встречный вопрос - почему не jQuery? То, что в синтаксисе jQuery поместилось в 7 строк с объявлением, чистоганом будет х10 строк минимум. Как раз для таких задач его и создавали.

Comment: С новыми стандартами ES6 он почти так же легок и понятен как JQuery да и синтаксис нативного мне больше нравится) Не могу пока победить плавную прокрутку только)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему может не работать js-анимация на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722375/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-js-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)