# Не работает скрипт плавной прокрутки на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я не особо силён в JS просто скачал скрипт плавной прокрутки. В уроке он работает а у меня нет.

Вот код

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
        let target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(target).offset() top
            },
            800
        );

    });
});
```

Мне сказали что всё дело в лишней ; после числа милесекунд. Удалил всё равно не работает. Смотрел через F12 в браузере показывает следующую ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Указывает на 6-ю строку. В чём дело не пойму.

Comment: Первое что бросается это отсутствие точки перед top `$(target).offset() top` должно быть`$(target).offset().top` ну и ссылки через якоря

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777379/178988