# Скролл до следующего блока

Tags: jquery

На странице с несколькими секциями есть фиксированный navbar, на нем имеется кнопка. Нужно написать скрипт, который будет плавно скролить до следующего блока при нажатии на эту кнопку, то есть можем нажать три раза и оказаться на третей секции.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777379/178988

Answer (score 0):

Решение на чистом JavaScript:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: gold;
}

.two {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.three {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.four {
  background-color: orange;
}

p {
  padding: 60px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"><button class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">Назад</button>
  <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Вперед</button></div>
<section class="section one">
  <p>Один</p>
</section>
<section class="section two">
  <p>Два</p>
</section>
<section class="section three">
  <p>Три</p>
</section>
<section class="section four">
  <p>Четыре</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Помимо такой кнопки есть еще меню слева с активными ссылками, а сама страница должна скроллится, то есть блоки не должны быть полноэкранными. А по нажатию на вперед назад должен происходить плавный скролл к секции выше/ниже

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.one, .two, .three, .four').height($(window).height());
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
$(document).ready(function() {
  var anchors = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  var currentIdx = 0;
  $('.scroll').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var full_url = this.href,
      parts = full_url.split('#'),
      btn = parts[1];
    if (btn == 'prev' && currentIdx > 0) {
      currentIdx--;
    } else if (btn == 'next' && currentIdx < anchors.length - 1) {
      currentIdx++;
    }
    var trgt = anchors[currentIdx],
      target_offset = $('#' + trgt).offset(),
      target_top = target_offset.top - 0;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target_top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.navbar {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 50px; line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

section {width: 100%; height: 100vh; padding: 60px 0 0 10px;}

.one {background-color: gold;}
.two {background-color: aqua;}
.three {background-color: darkseagreen;}
.four {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#prev" class="scroll"><button class="prev">Назад</button></a>
  <a href="#next" class="scroll"><button class="next">Вперед</button></a>
</div>
<section id="one" class="section one">
  <p>Один</p>
</section>
<section id="two" class="section two">
  <p>Два</p>
</section>
<section id="three" class="section three">
  <p>Три</p>
</section>
<section id="four" class="section four">
  <p>Четыре</p>
</section>
```