# Как остановить автоматический скролл при нажатии мышки?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть кнопка плавной прокрутки страницы на сайте.
Её код:

```
let scrollBtn = document.querySelector("#scroll-btn")

for (let link of document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]')) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let item = link.getAttribute('href');

        document.querySelector(item).scrollIntoView({
            block: "center",
            behavior: "smooth"
        })
    })
}
```

Возможно ли это сделать на чистом JS, без использования JQuery? Я нуб.

Comment: задача классическая. вот нашел [ссылку](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2018-06-08-plavnyj-skroll-do-elementa.html) на 4 варианта решения. у вас реализован 3 вариант из этой ссылки. обращаю внимание, что у вас не используется jquery.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777379/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю ваша прокрутка должна остановится, если задать новую.
Попробуйте выполнять `window.scrollTo( window.scrollX, window.scrollY );` при клике.

Возможно, будет правильнее вместо окна использовать родительский элемент
`item.parentNode.scrollTo( window.scrollX, window.scrollY );` так как `scrollIntoView` прокручивает именно его. Попробуйте оба варианта

```js
link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let item = link.getAttribute('href');

    document.querySelector(item).scrollIntoView({
        block: "center",
        behavior: "smooth"
    });

    const stopScroll = () => item.parentNode.scrollTo( window.scrollX, window.scrollY );
    document.body.addEventListener("click", () => stopScroll(), {once: true});

})
```